# How to create rule in pyomo which compares four decision variables?

Tags: python, pyomo

How to implement model constraint which revolves around comparing decision variables in pyomo?

I'm trying to create model representing multi-agent pathfinding problem, but i am struggling on rule specifying collision avoidance. Currently my approach looks like this:

```
def get_x(model, t, a):
    pos = model.spawns[a, 1]

    for tt in range(1, t):
        pos += model.moveRight[tt, a]
        pos -= model.moveLeft[tt, a]
    return pos
        

def get_y(model, t, a):
    pos = model.spawns[a, 2]

    for tt in range(1, t):
        pos += model.moveDown[tt, a]
        pos -= model.moveUp[tt, a]
    return pos


    agents_spawns = [
        [1, 1],
        [3, 9],
    ]

    agents_targets = [
        [5, 9],
        [9, 5]
    ]


    model = po.ConcreteModel("autonomus agents")

    model.time = po.RangeSet(20) # Max time for agents to reach target
    model.agents = po.RangeSet(2)

    model.width = po.RangeSet(10)
    model.height = po.RangeSet(10)
     
    model.spawns = po.Param(
        model.agents,
        po.RangeSet(2),
        initialize=lambda _,i,j: agents_spawns[i - 1][j - 1],
        within=po.Any,
    )

    model.targets = po.Param(
        model.agents,
        po.RangeSet(2),
        initialize=lambda _,i,j: agents_targets[i - 1][j - 1],
        within=po.Any,
    )
 
    model.moveRight = po.Var(
        model.time,
        model.agents,
        domain=po.Boolean,
    )

    model.moveLeft = po.Var(
        model.time,
        model.agents,
        domain=po.Boolean,
    )

    model.moveDown = po.Var(
        model.time,
        model.agents,
        domain=po.Boolean,
    )

    model.moveUp = po.Var(
        model.time,
        model.agents,
        domain=po.Boolean,
    )

    model.obj = po.Objective(rule=minmize_moves, sense=po.minimize)

    model.cons = po.ConstraintList()

    for agent in model.agents:
        model.cons.add(rule_reach_x(model, agent))
        model.cons.add(rule_reach_y(model, agent))
    

    for time in model.time:
        for agent in model.agents:
            model.cons.add(limit_speed(model, time, agent))
            
            if time == 1:
                continue
            
            x = get_x(model, time, agent)
            y = get_y(model, time, agent)

            model.cons.add(x >= 0)
            model.cons.add(x <= params["width"])
            model.cons.add(y >= 0)
            model.cons.add(x <= params["height"]) 
            
    
    for time in model.time:
        if time == 1:
            continue
        for agent, agent1 in combinations(model.agents, 2):
            x = get_x(model, time, agent)
            x1 = get_x(model, time, agent1)

            y = get_y(model, time, agent)
            y1 = get_y(model, time, agent1)
            # TODO somehow prevent collisions?
```

Finding present position of agent in time iteration 't' is based on summing and subtracting moves from spawn position on every iteraration.

I have big problem with implementing rule specyfying that no two agents can occupy same position. Simplest approach i tried `x != x1 or y != y1` throws error: `Cannot convert non-constant Pyomo expression (...) to bool`.

I know that i could use some kind of additional boolean variable trick, but i don't really get how to implement this for multidimensional Var like here.

How can i do that? Or are there any simpler ways to handle those collisions?

Comment: Use something like `x[i,t,p] = 1 if agent i occupies position p at time t and 0 otherwise`.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen But how could i synchronise this Var with current position of my agents? I get the latter part with suming and bounding x te be less at one t and p to be less than 1, but the part of creating it is confusing for me. In my code i use functions `get_x(model,t ,a)` and `get_y(....)`  for acquiring current positions, but the problem is i cant even index another Var with results of them like `x[agent, time, get_x(...), get_y(...)]` without getting errors. Another problem i have with this Var, is how to even set unocupied places to 0?

Comment: *how to even set unocupied places to 0* You don't. It is taken care of by design. If you want, you can write `occupied[t,p] = sum(i, x[i,t,p])`. Obviously, you need to think this through more carefully.